# radio button change event not firing with xzoom gallery, jquery script conflict issue ("TypeError: $(...).hammer is not a function")

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**radio button change event not firing with xzoom gallery, jquery script conflict issue ("TypeError: $(...).hammer is not a function")**

I have implemented xzoom image-gallery on one page.. but on same page, radio button change-event not getting fire.

If I comment xzoom gallery, then radio button change-event works properly.

**Above problem is only for mobile devices**

My radio button change call code snippet (work proper for desktops):

```
$('input[name="cartproddet"]').on('change', function(){
    //code here
})
```

[image]

**screenshot error only appears during mobile devices**

**please suggest me changes.. to enable radio button change-event with xzoom-gallery on same page**

open source xzoom-image gallery jquery libraries included as follow:

```
<script src="<?php echo asset_url('front'); ?>/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo asset_url('front'); ?>/js/setup.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo asset_url('front'); ?>/js/xzoom.min.js"></script>
```

I am not giving online js-links

Comment: Can we please get any code pertinent to "Hammer"?

Comment: @EGC for xzoom gallery.. there are.. jquery libraries on their website.. 1) xzoom.min.js 2) setup.js

Comment: Could you update your post with links to these as I guarantee 90% of people aren't willing to hunt them down for you? :S

Comment: @SebastianSimon please check added links & details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to all for help.. but I customize setup.js as follow:

**I replaced**

```
$(this).hammer().on("tap", function(event) { //some code })
```

**With**

```
$(this).on("tap", function(event) { //some code })
```

Its working now for destop as well as mobile devices :)